# Qooxdoo - what's the easiest way to include a specific qx class into the API

Tags: request, qooxdoo

I'm trying to include `qx.io.reques` in my application but i can't seem to find the right way to do it!

I tried to configure the `configure.json` file and added `"API_INCLUDE": ["qx.io.request*"]` in `let` section and ran the file again but it didn't work.

Running `./configure.py source-all` fixes it but makes it very slow to load the application because it's loading all the classes in the api, i need only the default classes along with `qx.io.request`.

I read the documentation in qooxdoo [website](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.0.4/pages/tool/generator_config_ref.html#pages-tool-generator-config-ref-extend) but i couldn't understand all the different options and which one works for me.

i want to enable xhr requests in my application so that i can send ajax requests, is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else run through the same problem, i found two ways to do it:

---

1- Run the generate.py file using `source-all` flag, this would include all the available classes in the api.

```
./generate.py source-all
```

then run the generate.py file without flages, this will remove all unnecessary classes and leave the ones used by your application.

```
./generate.py
```

---

2- Edit the file `configure.json` and scroll to the `"let":` section and add the property `"API_INCLUDE"` and set it's value to whatever classes you want to include in your application like this:

```
"let":
{
    "API_INCLUDE"  :    ["qx.io.request.*", "qx.ui.toolbar.*"],
    "API_EXECLUDE" :   .....
}
```

then run the generate.py file with `api` flag:

```
./generate.py api
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you are trying to include a class into your application. In qooxdoo, you simply do that by **using** the class. So if you want to make an Ajax request, you simply write code in your application that uses one of qooxdoo's IO classes, e.g.

```js
var req = new qx.io.request.Xhr("/some/path/file.ext");
```

and let the Generator include the *Xhr* class in your application.

This will happen with the next run of `./generate.py source` or similar (there is no `./configure.py` what you wrote). An exception is, as you wrote in your own answer, running the `source-all` job as it includes *all known classes* into the app, so the build will work whatever classes you are actually using. As for documentation, jobs are documented [here](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/pages/tool/generator/default_jobs_actions.html#source).

So generally speaking, you will normally not need to make any configuration changes, in order to use a specific class from the framework, you just use it in your code. If for some reason a class is not included *although you actually use it and have re-build the application*, you can use the [include](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_ref.html#include) config key to force the inclusion of this class. But this should be a rare exception.

The [API_INCLUDE](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0.x/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_macros.html) macro you mention only influences the generated API **documentation** which is entirely different from your application itself. (An application is usually not referred to as being an "API"). To see the difference just run `./generate.py source` and open `source/index.html`, as opposed to running `./generate.py api` and opening `api/index.html`. The first is your application, the second the API documentation for your application.

Comment: thanks Thomas for your answer, i'm a noob in qooxdoo. do you mean that all i need to do is write my class and then run `./generate.py` (i meant actually ./generate.py instead of ./configure.py in my answer, i just corrected it) and all required qooxdoo classed used in my custom class will be included automatically?